# Add the excerpt back to the question title on hover

Tags: script, questions, sites

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Quickly assess if a question is worth opening by hovering over the title. (This restores a feature that was removed for performance reasons by Stack Exchange.)

> [image: excerpts on hover]
> <sub>*Click image for animated Gif*</sub>

### About

In 2017, the feature that showed an excerpt of the question in the title tooltip when hovered was removed for performance reasons. This scripts adds that feature back by leveraging the Stack API. The script is for users that prefer using the main page as their primary starting point and then only visit the full Q&A when the excerpt seems to be interesting.

The original version was posted on Meta: [Hover text (title attribute) missing in question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292290)

#### License

The source code is released under the MIT license.

#### Download

You can download the script [here](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/blob/master/AddExcerptToTitle.user.js)
Or direct [install in your user script manager](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/raw/master/AddExcerptToTitle.user.js).

#### Platform

The script runs on any modern browser with a decent UserScript manager installed. The script will probably not run on GreaseMonkey v4.0, and I have no intention to put effort in to fix any issues that originate from GM4. I tested on Chrome/TamperMonkey.

### Contact

The userscript is created by me, and you can post answers here to request features. For bug reports, please use the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/issues).

### Code

The code before version 0.4 was "vanilla" JavaScript with a bit of jQuery because Stack Exchange includes that already. Version 0.4 switched to using TypeScript 4.9 for quality-assurance reasons.

The code is found on GitHub as part of the [Small But Handy Repository](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy).

Pull Requests are appreciated. If you have question beforehand, feel free to drop me line in [Stack Apps chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27/stack-apps)